# Scheduled Tasks running twice on windows server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, .net, task-scheduler, .net-4.0

On my production server (Windows server 2012) I have scheduled various tasks. I have enabled Task Scheduler history but its of no use. `LastRunResult` of each of my tasks shows `Last run of the task was terminated by user` which means authenticated program had terminated this task. But there is no such program configured which may stop all these tasks. Because of this tasks are not getting completed.

How can I track which program/task caused this? There is a huge time difference between these scheduled tasks so what could be the issue?